# What do these curly brackets do?

Tags: java, swing

This is a piece of code that was generated by netbeans and I'm confused as to what those brackets do after it calls `AbstractListModel`.

```
    li_reminderslist.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel() {
        String[] strings = { };
        public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
        public Object getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
    });
```

Sorry for the beginner question. I tried look for a tutorial on it, but couldn't find one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It creates an [Anonymous Inner Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html).

Basically, you're creating a new instance of `AbstractListModel`, but overriding a few things. Since you're only going to use it in this one place, there's no point in creating a whole separate class declaration with its own name—hence the "anonymous" part.

On a side note, since Java 8 [Lambda Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) serve a similar function to Anonymous Inner Classes, but they're specifically used for instantiating classes/interfaces with only one abstract/unimplemented method.

Comment: The OP might want to also take note of (and investigate) anonymous arrays, which operate on much the same principal.  Very useful for creating arrays "on the spot", when an extra declaration is just too "wordy".

Comment: @tgm1024 Thanks! I was looking for something like this!

Answer (score 2):

This is implementation of anonymous inner class.

For example you may create new `Runnable`:

```
new Runnable() {public void run() { }});
```

or `ActionListener`

```
new ActionListener(){public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e}{}};
```

in the same manner.